# How can I trigger dialogflow event from detect intent API?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

How can trigger event in dialogflow from python detect intent API.
I want to trigger welcome intent as soon as I start my chat window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to send the "WELCOME" Event as part of the query input to the call to `detect_intent()`. It might look something like this

```
import dialogflow

client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

session = client.session_path('[PROJECT]', '[SESSION]')

event_input = dialogflow.types.EventInput(name='WELCOME', language_code='en-US')
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(event=event_input)
response = client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
```